# how to ask user to input values untill he chose to exit in simple calculator

Tags: python

```
def add(x,y):
    return x+y
def sub(x,y):
    return x-y
def mul(x,y):
    return x\*y
def div(x,y):
    return float(x/y)

print('Please select operation -\\n"   
        "1. Add\\n"   
        "2. Subtract\\n"   
        "3. Multiply\\n"   
        "4. Divide\\n"  
        "5. Exit \\n')
select = int(input("Select operations from 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5:"))
if select==5:
    exit()
x=int(input("Enter 1st number:"))
y=int(input("Enter 2nd numbers:"))
i=0
while (i\>select):
    if select==1:
        print("The addition of values is:",add(x,y))
    elif select==2:
        print("The subtraction of values is:",sub(x,y))
    elif select==3:
        print("The multiplication of values is:",mul(x,y))
    elif select==4:
        print("The division of values is:",div(x,y))
    else:
        print("Invalid output")  
    i+=1
```

my output is like this

Please select operation -
"         "1. Add
"         "2. Subtract
"         "3. Multiply
"         "4. Divide
Select operations from 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5:2
Enter 1st number:5
Enter 2nd numbers:6
PS C:\Users\princ\OneDrive\Desktop\Python>

Comment: Your `while` loop should start after your function definitions being an endless loop `while(True)`, because you get out with `if select==5: exit()`.

Comment: @JohnOmielan it not asking prompt from user again.

Comment: Yes, because all your `input` is done outside the `while` loop, so it just runs once.

Comment: Did you notice the syntax errors in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are placing the while loop incorrectly, you should be placing it above your select statement to allow user to select the operation again and again. The while loop above if else is basically useless (apart from sending you in a infinite loop or something else because you don't even have a break statement). There are multiple other things that are incorrect but basically your program can work by this

```
def add(x,y):
    return x+y
def sub(x,y):
    return x-y
def mul(x,y):
    return x*y
def div(x,y):
    return float(x/y)

print('''Please select operation
        1. Add  
        2. Subtract  
        3. Multiply   
        4. Divide
        5. Exit''')

while (True):
    select = int(input("Select operations from 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5:"))
    
    if select==5:
        exit()

    x=int(input("Enter 1st number:"))
    y=int(input("Enter 2nd numbers:"))

    if select==1:
        print("The addition of values is:",add(x,y))
    elif select==2:
        print("The subtraction of values is:",sub(x,y))
    elif select==3:
        print("The multiplication of values is:",mul(x,y))
    elif select==4:
        print("The division of values is:",div(x,y))
    else:
        print("Invalid output")
```

Also if you want to show operation list everytime just move the while loop above print statement.